# Get distinct on only one column on a multi column query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

> Let me try to explain my weird requirement.

On SQL Server 2008, say we have a `table` with `column1` & `column2`.

We need to get distinct values only for the `column1`. When we do `select distinct column1, column2 from table order by someColumn`

Tried using joins, sub-queries etc but unable to find a solution.

Current output `column-zero` is duplicated

```
column-zero column-One  column-Two  column-Three
00074347303 401136  1144970 2015-09-21
30237890006 132384  855185  2015-11-06
50419020801 1917840 747677  2015-10-26
00074347303 300852  652090  2015-07-09
00074347303 307440  574437  2015-04-15
00074347303 307440  574437  2015-06-16
00074347303 131760  572546  2015-09-23
00074347303 150975  572485  2015-10-05
00074347303 148779  572485  2015-09-25
00074347303 148779  572485  2015-08-03
00074347303 99186   572485  2015-10-06
00074347303 99552   570289  2015-09-15
00074347303 99552   570289  2015-08-26
00074347303 153720  569313  2015-05-21
00074347303 258640  567117  2015-04-06
52544018876 81618   507398  2015-06-10
55513073001 134322  428830  2015-06-03
55513073001 134322  428830  2015-07-09
55513073001 137982  425109  2015-09-25
55513073001 137982  425109  2015-08-05
```

Expected output `column-zero` is distinct

```
column-zero column-One  column-Two  column-Three
00074347303 401136  1144970 2015-09-21
30237890006 132384  855185  2015-11-06
50419020801 1917840 747677  2015-10-26
00074347303 300852  652090  2015-07-09
52544018876 81618   507398  2015-06-10
55513073001 134322  428830  2015-06-03
```

Comment: Show us: (1) sample table data, and (2) the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh - please look at the data. This is going in our nerves now

Comment: @student what do you want the output to be?

Comment: And the expected result?

Comment: @jarlh Let me update my question, 1 minute

Comment: @student well can you post the expected result?

Comment: @dood Let me update my question, 1 minute

Comment: @jarlh - I have updated my question

Comment: @dood I've updated my question

Comment: @student - please make clear, WHICH values you need from the other columns? any value? first value? avg value?

Comment: u need to group only for coloumn zero and have the other coloumns in aggregate-functions like MIN() or MAX()

Comment: I only needed `column-zero` to be distinct, rest can be duplicated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Abihabi87's answer may or may not work, depending in dbms.)

Comment: @student try to show me how column-zero has one value and column-one has multiple values. For example for column-zero = '00074347303'. 'cause Group is what you are asking for, but you don't want to use an aggregate-function. What is you want exactly?

Comment: Yes, that is only the way by using aggregate function because you can have unique value in other columns so in such data set you can't perform DISTINCT operation for single column with the set of rest of columns.

Comment: Do you want rows held together? Or just any combination of column1, column2 and column3 - no matter if the values comes from different rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED according to question-edit**

WHAT you need is not distinct, but grouping

```
select col0, avg(col1), avg(col2), avg(col3) from table group by col0
```

Or try other aggregate function meeting your requirement: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp
for mssql see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Comment: please try my updated answer. if you could show, which values you really need of col1-3, i could update again

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
select
distinct on (exe.column1) exe.column1,exe.column2
from
(
select
column1,
column2
from table 
order by someColumn
) exe
```

Comment: What us `exe` here?

Comment: the alias for the subselect